# Finding locus of point of intersection of pair of tangents

Tags: conic-sections

A pair of tangents to conic $ax^2+by^2=1$ intercepts a constant distance 2k on the y-axis. Prove that locus of their intersection is the conic.

$ax^2(ax^2+by^2-1)=bk^2(ax^2-1)^2$

I tried by introducing two tangents with slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ and finding their $y$ intercept and equating it to 2k but not sure what to do after it.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combines equation of pair of tangents to the conic is given by $T^2=S'S$:
$$(axx'+byy'-1)^2= S'(ax^2+by^2-1), S'=(ax'^2+by'^2-1)~~~(1)$$
Let them cut $y$axis, put $x=0$ to get a quadratic in $y$ as
$$(byy'-1)^2=S'(by^2-1)=0 \implies (b^2y'^2-S'b) y^2-2by'y-S'=0$$
This gives $$y_1+y_2=2by'/(b^2y'^2-bS'), y_1y_2=-S'/(b^2y'^2-bS')$$
From these eqns we can get:
$$2k=y_1-y_2=\sqrt{(y_1+y_2)^2-y_1y_2} ~~~(2)$$
Get this equation (2) and put $x'=x$ and $y'=y$, to get the required locus of $(x', y')$.

Please note the the locus will not be  conic as it would not be a quadratic of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: understood, just one query why did you equate $ T^2=4S^'S $ and not $ T^2=S^'S $

Comment: @goku the factor of 4 was a mistake. I have corrected it now. Thanks.